# Install local gems via bundle on heroku not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rubygems, bundler

I'm trying to install my app to heroku.  But I'm having an issue with a gem.  Its a private gem and we don't have a private gem server setup, so I've cloned the gem locally as a submodule inside the app.

When I push to heroku I get this error:

```
 !     Warning: Multiple default buildpacks reported the ability to handle this app. The first buildpack in the list below will be used.

        Detected buildpacks: Ruby,Node.js

        See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#buildpack-detect-order

-----> Ruby app detected

-----> Compiling Ruby/Rails

-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.5.1

-----> Installing dependencies using bundler 1.15.2

   Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment

   Warning: the running version of Bundler (1.15.2) is older than the version that created the lockfile (1.16.2). We suggest you upgrade to the latest version of Bundler by running `gem install bundler`.

   You are trying to install in deployment mode after changing

   your Gemfile. Run `bundle install` elsewhere and add the

   updated Gemfile.lock to version control.



   The gemspecs for path gems changed

   Bundler Output: Warning: the running version of Bundler (1.15.2) is older than the version that created the lockfile (1.16.2). We suggest you upgrade to the latest version of Bundler by running `gem install bundler`.

   You are trying to install in deployment mode after changing

   your Gemfile. Run `bundle install` elsewhere and add the

   updated Gemfile.lock to version control.



   The gemspecs for path gems changed

 !

 !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.

 !

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.

 !     Push failed
```

When I removed the locally install gem it all worked fine.

So strong hunch is that bundler 1.15.2 handles local gems differently and it's causing a conflict.

In my Gemfile, not inside any group, I have `gem 'portkey', path: './gems/portkey/'`

At the top of my Gemfile.lock I have

```
PATH
  remote: gems/portkey
  specs:
    portkey (0.1.10)
      bitly
      omniauth-google-oauth2 (~> 0.5.3)
      rails (~> 5.2.1)
      rebrandly
      shortener (~> 0.8.0)
      will_paginate
```

Heroku doesn't support bundler 1.16.2 yet afaik

I'm using rails 5/ruby-2.5 and I don't seem be able to downgrade bundler to 1.15.2 and generate an older version of the lockfile

I can't easily make this gem accessible any other way.

I'm stumped how I can make the install of this gem work, and suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue, solved by upgrading to Bundler 2.0.1 (which is now supported by Heroku).

For 1.x version they still use 1.15.2 though.